# How to expand or collapse child page depends on dynamic content?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi what is the best way to expand or collapse child page depending on dynamic content in .net web application?

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Basic_Show_and_Hide) is a client side approach (Javascript) to hiding and showing elements on the screen. As for the server side, you'll have to check the content and if its determined that you want something hidden, you can set the `.Visible` property of the item to be false and it won't be rendered to the page.

Comment: OK. I see. Can you show me how to bind server to client side? because the page builds dynamically.